# Sum of two prime numbers

Tags: python, data-structures

I wrote a python code to express the given number if possible to express them as sum of prime numbers.
For example,14 = 7+7
But if I give 14 the else block gets printed and my output returns as can't be expressed as sum of primes. Please tell me where did I go wrong

```
def isPrime(n):
    prime = False
    if(n == 0 or n == 1):
        prime = False
    else:
        for i in range(2,n//2+1):
            if(n%i==0):
                prime = False
    
    return prime

def sum_of_two(n):
    for i in range(2,n//2+1):
        if(isPrime(i)):
            if(isPrime(n-i)):
                return("{num1} is expressed as sum of {num2} and {num3}".format(num1=n,num2=i,num3=n-i))
        else:
            return"Can't be expressed as sum of primes"
n = int(input())
print(sum_of_two(n))
```

Comment: `if(isPrime(n)):` -- is that really what you mean? 14 is not prime. Maybe you mean `if isPrime(i):`.

Comment: In your own words, if you call `sum_of_two(14)`, what do you expect is the *very first* value that will be passed to `isPrime`? (Hint: what is the first line of code in `sum_of_two` that mentions `isPrime`?) Is that value prime? (Hint: what is `2 * 7` equal to?)

Comment: Oh meant to say i as im expressing n as i and n-i. But even after changing it to i its shows the same output

Comment: `isPrime` can never return `True`.

Comment: The `else` in `sum_of_two` is also going to make the program return too early. You only want to return with a failure message if you've gone all the way through the loop without finding a result.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes the isPrime(7) will be true hence it will move to the second loop for n-i where it checks isPrime(7) and hence it should print 14 is expressed as 7 + 7

Comment: @Blckknght Yes that was kind of the intention because I wanted the both the numbers used to express the input numbers to be strictly prime. So even if one is not prime the else block must be printed

Comment: @SreelakshmiG: Consider 18, though. Once you hit 4, the loop exits. But 5+13 is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, u have to make 2 minor changes.
Firstly, in your isPrime function, the boolean of Prime is never set to true in anycase. Therefore, since you are checking if it has a factor and making it false, changing it to True in line 2 will solve that.

Also, in your sum of 2 you need to change the first if condition to "i" instead of n, since the second is n-i. (i + n-i =n as opposed to n+n-i). Therefore the final code is as follows.

```
def isPrime(n):
    prime = True  #change made here
    if(n == 0 or n == 1):
        prime = False
    else:
        for i in range(2,n//2+1):
            if(n%i==0):
                prime = False
    
    return prime

def sum_of_two(n):
    for i in range(2,n//2+1):
        if(isPrime(i)):  #change made here
            if(isPrime(n-i)):
                return("{num1} is expressed as sum of {num2} and {num3}".format(num1=n,num2=i,num3=n-i))
        else:
            return"Can't be expressed as sum of primes"
n = int(input())
print(sum_of_two(n))
```

I have highlighted the 2 changes using comments.

Comment: okay now I could see why my code was affected because of the flag boolean value in the front.Thanks

Comment: One more. I believe the `else` block in `sum_of_two(n)` needs to be outdented to become part of the `for` loop. Otherwise, the loop can return "Can't be expressed..." prematurely. For example, it will report 18 can't be expressed as a sum of primes, but it can be expressed as 5 + 13.

Comment: ... or the `else` could be eliminated entirely and the second `return` could just be the next statement after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrime(n):
    prime = True  # change made here
    if(n == 0 or n == 1):
        prime = False
    else:
        for i in range(2, n//2+1):
            if(n % i == 0):
                prime = False

    return prime


def sum_of_two(n):
    for i in range(2, n//2+1):
        if(isPrime(i)):  # change made here
            if(isPrime(n-i)):
                return("{num1} is expressed as sum of {num2} and {num3}".format(num1=n, num2=i, num3=n-i))

    return"Can't be expressed as sum of primes"


n = int(input())
print(sum_of_two(n))
```

I think it have to be changed like this. Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sieve of Eratosthenes for this instead of re-evaluating the primality of numbers individually:

```
def primeSplit(n):
    isPrime = [0,0]+[1]*(n-2) # sieve of Eratosthenes
    p,inc = 2,1
    while p<n:
        if isPrime[p]: # only check primes as you find them
            isPrime[p*p::p] = [0]*len(range(p*p,n,p)) # update sieve
            if n-p <= p and isPrime[n-p]:             # check prime pair 
                return f"{n} is expressed as sum of {p} and {n-p}"
        p,inc = p+inc,2 # next potential prime
    return f"{n} can't be expressed as sum of primes"

for n in range(1000000,1000020):
    print(primeSplit(n))
    
1000000 is expressed as sum of 500057 and 499943
1000001 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000002 is expressed as sum of 500029 and 499973
1000003 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000004 is expressed as sum of 500107 and 499897
1000005 is expressed as sum of 1000003 and 2
1000006 is expressed as sum of 500153 and 499853
1000007 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000008 is expressed as sum of 500029 and 499979
1000009 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000010 is expressed as sum of 500041 and 499969
1000011 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000012 is expressed as sum of 500069 and 499943
1000013 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000014 is expressed as sum of 500041 and 499973
1000015 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000016 is expressed as sum of 500113 and 499903
1000017 can't be expressed as sum of primes
1000018 is expressed as sum of 500009 and 500009
1000019 can't be expressed as sum of primes
```